# Backbone bind event when reload template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js

I just started to lean Backbone, and underscore template, not sure if the structure suitable for it.

The question is, when I reload a template, how to re-bind event from Backbone which is re-run the events function.

The example is simply load an index page, insert main_option template into the page, and jump between main_option, and role_view template.

Here is the app.js which I put router in there:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'views/role_view', 'views/main_options'], function ($, _, Backbone, rolePage, mainOptions) {

var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    $el: $('.container'),

    initialize: function () {
        this.mainOptionPage = mainOptions;
        this.loginView = rolePage;

    },

    routes: {
        "": "mainOption",
        "views/role_view": "login"
    },

    mainOption: function () {

        this.$el.html(this.mainOptionPage.render().$el);
    },

    login: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.loginView.render().$el);

    }
});

var router = new appRouter();
Backbone.history.start();

});
```

Here is the main_option.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone){

var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Guest Worker',
        age: 23,
        occupation: 'worker'
    }
});

var testView = Backbone.View.extend({
    $el: $('#indexPage'),

    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;
        $.get('/test/templates/mainOptions.html').success(function (data) {
            self.template_loaded(data);
            template = _.template(data, {name: "Test"});
        }, 'html');

    },
    events: {
        'click .signButton': 'pageToSign'
    },



    pageToSign: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        Backbone.history.navigate("views/role_view", {trigger: true});
    },

    template_loaded: function (html) {
        var template = _.template(html, {name: "Test"});

        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
    }
});
var person = new Person;

return new testView({model: person});
});
```

and final page is role_view.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone){

var role = Backbone.View.extend({


    initialize: function(){
        var self = this;

        $.get('/test/templates/chooseRole.html').success(function(html){
            self.template_loaded(html);
        });
    },

    events: {
        'click .parentButton': 'parentClick'
    },

    template_loaded: function(html) {
        var template = _.template(html, {name: "Test"});

        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
    },

    parentClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Backbone.history.navigate("", {trigger: true});
    }


});

return new role();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You real problem is that you're reusing views rather than destroying and creating them as needed. In your router, you have this:

```
mainOption: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.mainOptionPage.render().$el);
},
login: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.loginView.render().$el);
}
```

You call `this.$el.html` the first time, the view goes up, and everything seems to be okay. Then you switch views by calling `this.$el.html` and everything still seems to be okay. But the next time you switch views, your events are gone. This happens because of the way jQuery's `html` function works; from the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2):

> When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. **Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.**

Emphasis mine. Calling `this.$el.html` will destroy the event bindings on the previous content (such as `this.mainOptionsPage.el` or `this.loginView.el`).

If you create and destroy views as needed:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone){
    // Your Person model goes in its own file or possibly in the router file for now...
    var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
        //...
    });
    return TestView; // Return the view "class", not an instance.
});

define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone){
    var Role = Backbone.View.extend({
        //...
    });
    return Role;
});

define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'views/role_view', 'views/main_options', 'models/person'], function ($, _, Backbone, Role, TestView, Person) {
    var person = new Person; // The person model is managed here.
    var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        //...
        initialize: function () {
            // Don't need anything in here anymore.
        },
        //...
        mainOption: function () {
            // Create a new view when we need it.
            this.switchTo(new TestView({ model: person }));
        },
        login: function() {
            // Create a new view when we need it.
            this.switchTo(new Role);
        },
        switchTo: function(view) {
            // Destroy the old view since we don't need it anymore.
            if(this.currentView)
                this.currentView.remove();

            // Keep track of the new current view so that we can
            // kill it alter and avoid leaks.
            this.currentView = view;

            this.$el.html(this.currentView.render().el);
        }
    });
    //...
});
```